# Schema.org Type for Online Business

Tags: schema.org

I have a site that is a website/online store for the company. The main goal of the site is to sell the company's product.

In looking to markup the site I am stuck as to what type I should choose.

[Organization](http://schema.org/Organization) would work but that is really broad. [Corporation](http://schema.org/Corporation) is a bit more specific but still really broad. I thought about using [Store](http://schema.org/Store) but my concern with using that one is it falls under Local Business. This business is online only, no local store front.

What type should I choose? Is it okay to use `Store` for an online business even if it doesn't have a local store front?

Also, I've considered using productontology to add an `additionalType` but there really isn't another type that I can think of.

Comment: You have my empathy. Schema.org is fairly limited.

Comment: @closetnoc - You would think they would have a schema for online stores. Oh well.

Comment: What drives me nuts about schema.org and Google is that there are too many assumptions made which completely block out of their thinking perfectly valid content, sites, and reasons for existence. On example that cracks me up is that Google hates site with automated content... but is that not what Google is?? Schema.org was lead primarily by Google and far from complete. In fact, there has been little movement on the schema since it was created. And now Google is said to be making mark-up a (required) ranking factor?? Excuse me? It does not apply well at all and you think this is a good idea?

Comment: @closetnoc - I agree. `And now Google is said to be making mark-up a (required) ranking factor?? Excuse me?` Do you have a source for that? Would love to read on this in more detail but I agree with you.

Comment: It was one of the many things I read somewhere researching something else... I do not think it has happened of course, but one of those things they dropped a hint about. It would be on one of the big-boys SEO sites and not a SEO parrot site. I cannot remember where. Sorry. The word was that mark-up on the site would be required to rank. I took it as a trust metric. That does not make sense to me. But Google does silly *** **** sometimes so I do not doubt it. As for my site, I would ask what could I possibly mark-up?? Anything?? Short answer. Nothing. I will see if I can find it later.

Comment: I was starting to sweat... Where the heck did I see that?? Was I imagining it?? Have I lost my mind?? Am I starting a nasty rumor?? (which I like to do for fun by the way) No. This is likely what I saw: http://searchengineland.com/google-may-add-structured-markup-data-to-ranking-algorithm-230402

Comment: Okay. Now I remember. It is partly a trust thing but not necessarily site trust. Google currently sees markup as a tick in the trust category and the knowledge graph is partially based upon this. Where the knowledge graph started with only trusted sources, it now also takes markup that can be confirmed in more than one place to a reasonable level of probability and will use it in the knowledge graph. So while the article denies it, pages with markup will rank higher now but more importantly if there are facts that can be confirmed, the page will outrank nearly everyone.

Comment: I was researching semantics regarding knowledge graphs and acquisition of facts as well as retrieval using vectors. I was reading known research papers and did a general search on the web for other non-Google semantics information and came across an article that was more than half right and very good. I then poked around before regaining my focus. Going to bed... ;-) I often read late at night. Hence why I barely remembered it. I will write more on this here if I get a chance.

Comment: @closetnoc - :) I've been there too many times... "Where did I read that?" Thank you for finding the link. Interesting to read on Google's "possible" plans.

Comment: Actually, part of this already exists. If someone asks a question, I will try and explain how confirmed facts are being added to the knowledge graph and how these search results can find their way to the top of the SERPs. Much of the mechanics exist now. The question is how often does it actually happen? That article is somewhat misleading but important none-the-less. I was ironically just on a site that mentions this though the article is fairly weak. I rather suspect I can find some evidence. I am researching Googles natural biases though I will defend Google on some of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your concern about `Store` is valid. The type [`Store`](http://schema.org/Store) is a sub-type of [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness), which is for *physical* businesses. So it should not be used for online-only shops.

For the business running the shop, [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) (or the more specific [`Corporation`](http://schema.org/Corporation), if it applies) is the appropriate choice.

This allows you to use the [`makesOffer`](http://schema.org/makesOffer)/[`offeredBy`](http://schema.org/offeredBy) property.